# Getting Original Indices of Reordered Array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array of numbers `A`, and I want to create a new array `B` representing the indicies of `A` after `A` is reordered from smallest to largest.

For example:

```
A = [50 10 60 90 30];
```

The reordered `A` would then be:

```
A = [10 30 50 60 90];
```

And I want to get the output:

```
B = [2 5 1 3 4];
```

These indices in `B` therefore correspond to the original indices in `A`, but are written in the order of the reordered `A`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second output of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sort.html):

```
[A_sorted, B] = sort(A);
```